# Differences between replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '') and replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

**Are there differences between these two?**

```
replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Also, are there any significant differences in time using one or another?

**edit:** about the performance, I did some testing http://jsperf.com/myregexp-test

Comment: Be aware of what it actually does. Try `"naïve".replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');`

Comment: @NullUserException but in the end there isn't a solution in JS to this problem. Even `\W` does the same.

Comment: @xanatos: That is not strictly true. The [XRegExp plugin for Javascript](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) gives access to the Unicode general category, script, and block properties that Javascript on its own so scandalously neglects.  That means that with it you can use the `\pL` and `\pN` and such, as well as `\p{Latin}`, `\p{Common}`, etc.

Comment: +1 I didn't know there was a JS replacement for Regex. Very good to know.

Comment: @ogps92: With Unicode casefolding, `/[A-Z]/i` can pick up things that `/[a-zA-Z]/` misses.  For example, `ſ` U+017F `LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S` and `K` U+212A `KELVIN SIGN` under simple casefolding, and potentially if you had a `+` perhaps also multicharacter folds like `ß`  U+00DF `LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S` and `ﬀ`  FB00 `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF`. However, Javascript doesn’t support Unicode case-insensitive matches, but nearly everything else does, so don’t get too complacent. In general `\pL` is how to pick up all letters and `\p{Lu}` the uppercase ones, but you need `XRegExp` for that.

Comment: What does g / gi at the end of regex used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, by the first, the `i` at the end makes the regex case insensitive meaning that it doesn't matter if the letter it finds is upper- or lower-case.

The second matches upper- and lower-case letters but makes sure they are either upper- or lower-case. So you end up with the same result.

Comment: Be aware that this is not generally true.  For example, `Σ`, `σ`, and `ς` are all case-insensitively equivalent, and you could not get them all if you simply enumerated two of them in a character class like `[Σσ]`, as that would miss the final sigma, `ς`. Because Javascript doesn’t support Unicode, you’re screwed here, but in a real^H^H^H^Hnormal language, casefolding would pick up all of them in a `/Σ/i` match.